# Masonry function not recognised

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, masonry

Question: I'm getting an error saying my jQuery file doesn't understand my masonry function. I have loaded the jquery.min.js file first, then the masonry file and then my costum jquery file.. (using wordpress, in the header though)

error:

Uncaught TypeError: container.masonry is not a function

code:

```
$( window ).load( function()
{
    // jQuery
    var container = jQuery('.news .masonry .row');
// initialize
    container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.col-md-6'
    });
});
```

Comment: can you post your html too ?

Comment: It might be that your masonry plugin is not included, or the selector is not finding the element ".news .masonry .row"

Comment: some times there is a confusion in jQuery so try directly : $('.news .masonry .row').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.col-md-6'
    });

Comment: That was it! Great, thanks!